# Upgrade openSSL on Centos 5.6 (32bit)

Tags: security, ssl, openssl, centos5

I've got `OpenSSL 0.9.8e - Release: 27.el5_10.4` installed on my CentOS 5.6 (32bit) system and I want to upgrade to at least 0.9.8f because from that version OpenSSL supports SNI for SSL certificates.

Is this possible and how do I do this?
When I type `yum info openssl` the current installed version (0.9.8e) is the latest available version.

Comment: Can you update by downloading, compiling and installing from source?

Comment: Can.. yes (is my own server) but is is smart?